# How should I implement lazy session creation in PHP?

Tags: php, session

By default, PHP's session handling mechanisms set a session cookie header and store a session even if there is no data in the session. If no data is set in the session then I don't want a `Set-Cookie` header sent to the client in the response and I don't want an empty session record stored on the server. If data is added to `$_SESSION`, then the normal behavior should continue.

My goal is to implement lazy session creation behavior of the sort that Drupal 7 and [Pressflow](https://launchpad.net/pressflow) where no session is stored (or session cookie header sent) unless data is added to the `$_SESSION` array during application execution. The point of this behavior is to allow reverse proxies such as [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/) to cache and serve anonymous traffic while letting authenticated requests pass through to Apache/PHP. Varnish (or another proxy-server) is configured to pass through any requests without cookies, assuming correctly that if a cookie exists then the request is for a particular client.

I have ported the session handling code from Pressflow that uses `session_set_save_handler()` and overrides the implementation of `session_write()` to check for data in the `$_SESSION` array before saving and will write this up as library and add an answer here if this is the best/only route to take.

**My Question:** While I can implement a fully custom `session_set_save_handler()` system, is there an easier way to get this lazy session creation behavior in a relatively generic way that would be **transparent** to most applications?

Comment: @cletus: He stated his reason: *The point of this behavior is to allow reverse proxies such as Varnish to cache and serve anonymous traffic while letting authenticated requests pass through to Apache/PHP.*

Comment: Related Answer: [PHP Session class similar to CodeIgniter Session Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596082/php-session-class-similar-to-codeigniter-session-class-exists/11596538#11596538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have developed a [working solution](http://github.com/adamfranco/lazy_sessions) to this problem that uses `session_set_save_handler()` and a set of custom session storage methods that check for content in the `$_SESSION` array before writing out session data. If there is no data to write for the session, then `header('Set-Cookie:', true);` is used to prevent PHP's session-cookie from being sent in the response.

The latest version of this code as well as documentation and examples are [available on GitHub](http://github.com/adamfranco/lazy_sessions). In the code below, the important functions that make this work are `lazysess_read($id)` and `lazysess_write($id, $sess_data)`.

```
<?php
/**
 * This file registers session save handlers so that sessions are not created if no data
 * has been added to the $_SESSION array.
 * 
 * This code is based on the session handling code in Pressflow (a backport of
 * Drupal 7 performance features to Drupal 6) as well as the example code described
 * the PHP.net documentation for session_set_save_handler(). The actual session data
 * storage in the file-system is directly from the PHP.net example while the switching
 * based on session data presence is merged in from Pressflow's includes/session.inc
 *
 * Links:
 *      http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php
 *      http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pressflow/pressflow/6/annotate/head:/includes/session.inc
 *
 * Caveats:
 *      - Requires output buffering before session_write_close(). If content is 
 *        sent before shutdown or session_write_close() is called manually, then 
 *        the check for an empty session won't happen and Set-Cookie headers will
 *        get sent.
 *        
 *        Work-around: Call session_write_close() before using flush();
 *        
 *      - The current implementation blows away all Set-Cookie headers if the
 *        session is empty. This basic implementation will prevent any additional
 *        cookie use and should be improved if using non-session cookies.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright &copy; 2010, Middlebury College
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU General Public License (GPL), Version 3 or later.
 */ 

/*********************************************************
 * Storage Callbacks
 *********************************************************/

function lazysess_open($save_path, $session_name)
{
    global $sess_save_path;

    $sess_save_path = $save_path;
    return(true);
}

function lazysess_close()
{
    return(true);
}

function lazysess_read($id)
{ 
    // Write and Close handlers are called after destructing objects
    // since PHP 5.0.5.
    // Thus destructors can use sessions but session handler can't use objects.
    // So we are moving session closure before destructing objects.
    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

    // Handle the case of first time visitors and clients that don't store cookies (eg. web crawlers).
    if (!isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        return '';
    }

    // Continue with reading.
    global $sess_save_path;

    $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
    return (string) @file_get_contents($sess_file);
}

function lazysess_write($id, $sess_data)
{ 
    // If saving of session data is disabled, or if a new empty anonymous session
    // has been started, do nothing. This keeps anonymous users, including
    // crawlers, out of the session table, unless they actually have something
    // stored in $_SESSION.
    if (empty($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && empty($sess_data)) {

        // Ensure that the client doesn't store the session cookie as it is worthless
        lazysess_remove_session_cookie_header();

        return TRUE;
    }

    // Continue with storage
    global $sess_save_path;

    $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
    if ($fp = @fopen($sess_file, "w")) {
        $return = fwrite($fp, $sess_data);
        fclose($fp);
        return $return;
    } else {
        return(false);
    }

}

function lazysess_destroy($id)
{
    // If the session ID being destroyed is the one of the current user,
    // clean-up his/her session data and cookie.
    if ($id == session_id()) {
        global $user;

        // Reset $_SESSION and $user to prevent a new session from being started
        // in drupal_session_commit()
        $_SESSION = array();

        // Unset the session cookie.
        lazysess_set_delete_cookie_header();
        if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
        }
    }


    // Continue with destruction
    global $sess_save_path;

    $sess_file = "$sess_save_path/sess_$id";
    return(@unlink($sess_file));
}

function lazysess_gc($maxlifetime)
{
    global $sess_save_path;

    foreach (glob("$sess_save_path/sess_*") as $filename) {
        if (filemtime($filename) + $maxlifetime < time()) {
            @unlink($filename);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*********************************************************
 * Helper functions
 *********************************************************/

function lazysess_set_delete_cookie_header() {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();

    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.0') === 1) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 3600, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);
    }
    else {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 3600, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure']);          
    }
}

function lazysess_remove_session_cookie_header () {
    // Note: this implementation will blow away all Set-Cookie headers, not just
    // those for the session cookie. If your app uses other cookies, reimplement
    // this function.
    header('Set-Cookie:', true);
}

/*********************************************************
 * Register the save handlers
 *********************************************************/

session_set_save_handler('lazysess_open', 'lazysess_close', 'lazysess_read', 'lazysess_write', 'lazysess_destroy', 'lazysess_gc');
```

While this solution works and is mostly transparent to applications including it, it requires rewriting the entire session-storage mechanism rather than relying on the built-in storage mechanisms with a switch to save or not.

Comment: Caution: since this lib does not use locking at all, concurrent request might override content of each other.

Answer (score 6):

Well, one option would be to use a session class to start/stop/store data in the session.  So, you could do something like:

```
class Session implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $closed = false;
    protected $data = array();
    protected $name = 'mySessionName';
    protected $started = false;

    protected function __construct() {
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->name])) $this->start();
        $this->data = $_SESSION;
    }

    public static function initialize() {
        if (is_object($_SESSION)) return $_SESSION;
        $_SESSION = new Session();
        register_shutdown_function(array($_SESSION, 'close'));
        return $_SESSION;
    }

    public function close() {
        if ($this->closed) return false;
        if (!$this->started) {
            $_SESSION = array();
        } else {
            $_SESSION = $this->data;
        }
        session_write_close();
        $this->started = false;
        $this->closed = true;
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) { 
        return isset($this->data[$offset]); 
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if (!isset($this->data[$offset])) {
            throw new OutOfBoundsException('Key does not exist');
        }
        return $this->data[$offset]; 
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->set($offset, $value);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        if (isset($this->data[$offset])) unset($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        if (!$this->started) $this->start();
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function start() {
        session_name($this->name);
        session_start();
        $this->started = true;
    }
}
```

To use, at the start of your script call `Session::initialize()`.  It will replace $_SESSION with the object, and setup the lazy loading.  Afterward, you can just do

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
```

If the session isn't started, it will be, and the user_id key would be set to 1.  If at any point you wanted to close (commit) the session, just call `$_SESSION->close()`.

You'll probably want to add some more session management functions (such as destroy, regenerate_id, the ability to change the name of the session, etc), but this should implement the basic functionality you're after...

It's not a save_handler, it's just a class to manage your sessions.  If you really wanted to, you could implement ArrayAccess in the class, and on construct replace $_SESSION with that class (The benefit of doing that, is that way legacy code can still use session as they used to without calling `$session->setData()`).  The only downside is that I'm not sure if the serialization routine that PHP uses would work properly (You'd need to put back the array into $_SESSION at some point...  Probably with a `register_shutdown_function()`...

Comment: Is this still the most recommended solution? I've found so little about lazy sessions it makes me think theer is another solution.

Comment: Do not assign something else to the `$_SESSION` superglobal. PHP takes care of that variable and if session state changes that variable get's set/unset/lost and even PHP into nirvana. Like you should not do `$_SESSION = array()` you should not do `$_SESSION = new XYZ()`. Instead pass the class along.

Comment: instead of `new Session()` use `new self()` and you are able to rename the class to whatever you like

Comment: the above code misses to set the `started` property, so session_start() is called multiple times.

Comment: important note: when replacing `$_SESSION` with a object/class like this, you need to make sure that you dont have code which uses array-expecting functions, like `array_push($_SESSION, 'abc')` etc., as those don't support non-arrays (or classes which implement ArrayAccess)

Answer (score 0):

I created a lazy session proof of concept here:

- it uses the native php session handler and _SESSION array
- it only starts the session if a cookie has been sent or
- it starts the session if something has been added the $_SESSION array
- it removes the session if a session is started and $_SESSION is empty

Will extend it in the next days:

https://github.com/s0enke/php-lazy-session

Answer (score 0):

this topic is under discussion for a future php version
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/session-read_only-lazy_write